# How to set public property with angular 2 when initializing a component

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have service which returns data as expected when injected to a component. However when i subscribe to the service method and  assign the response to a public variable upon initialization of the component. The variable remained to be undefined

here is my service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  public errorMessage:string;

  private URL = 'MyUrl';  

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ){}

  getData(token:string) :Observable<Response>
  {
      return this.http.get(this.URL + 'somedata?token='+token)
                 .map(response => response.json())
                 .catch(this.ThrowError);
  }


  private ThrowError (error: any) 
  {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
    error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); 
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

  private ExctractData(res:Response)
  {
    let body    = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
  }
}
```

And here is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {



  public DataSet:any;

  public datasets:any;

  constructor(
    private DataService:DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getData();
    this.datasets = this.DataSet;
    console.log(this.DataSet); //Why this returns undefined while it has been set in this.getData function?

  }


  getData()
  {

    this.DataService.getData(localStorage.getItem('token'))
                     .subscribe(
                        DataSet =>this.DataSet = DataSet,
                        error => console.error('Error: ' + <any>error),
                        () => console.log('Completed!')
                      )
  }

}
```

My problems is with ngOnInit() seems it can't initialize the Dataset to new values any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You see 'undefined' in the console because of the async nature of Observable and subscribe.
The console.log method gets executed before the callback function of subscribe.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

That's because `this.getData()` will call `async method`. So its completely unknown to it that ***by what time*** data will be returned. On other side, `this.datasets = this.DataSet;` will be executed immediately after execution of `this.getData() (which calls async method)` line. So, obviously `this.Dataset` is not filled up with data yet and so it is undefined.

What you can do is,

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.getData();
  }


  getData()
  {
    // this is async call and its unknown that how long this process would take to fetch data.
    this.DataService.getData(localStorage.getItem('token'))
                     .subscribe(
                        DataSet =>{    
                           this.DataSet = DataSet;
                           console.log(this.DataSet)  //<<<<here it will print data to the console.
                        },
                        error => console.error('Error: ' + <any>error),
                        () => console.log('Completed!')
                      )
  }
```

Comment: Now i understand the concept but i need to access this data within ngOnInit i have tried using promises but no lucky still searching....